# What are some interesting example of Topological spaces $X$ with the property that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ does not depend on $x_0$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have just started to read about fundamental groups,so my question given below may be trivial for experts.

> What are some 'interesting' example of Topological spaces $X$ with the property that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ does not depend on $x_0$ ?

I know that if the space $X$ is path connected then $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ does not depend on the choice of $x_0$.What are some other examples of the spaces with the above property?

Comment: any totally disconnected space will do: the $\pi_1$s will all be trivial

Comment: If $X$ is not connected (so not path connected) but all of the components have this property and the group is independent of the choice of *component*, then you have this property for the space.

Comment: or a bit more generally, any space such that all of its path-connected components are homotopic to each other will have the property that all $\pi_1(X,x)$ are isomorphic. if you want something "interesting", take something like two copies of the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ joined by smooth arcs

Comment: that will give you a connected example

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki: I see,thanks!

Comment: It all comes down to path components, because $\pi_1(X,x_0) = \pi_1(P(x_0),x_0)$ where $P(x_0)\subset X$ is the path component of $X$ containing $x_0$.

Comment: @DanRust: your remark is true essentially because image of path connected space under continuous map is path connected?

Comment: Essentially, yes. In particular, the image of a circle (a loop) will always be contained in a single path component of the codomain of a continuous map because the circle is connected.

Comment: @DanRust: Yeah exactly same was in my mind,thanks!

Comment: At the risk of possibly confusing you, there is a counterpart to the fundamental group (actually an infinite family, but that really would be too much to think about for the moment) called $\pi_0$. Instead of considering base-pointed maps from the circle to $X$, one instead considers base-pointed maps from $S^0$ which is just a space with two points. In the same way, one considers homotopy classes of such maps, and one finds rather easily that $\pi_0$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the path components of $X$. I hope that helps with your intuition, but if not feel free to ignore this.

Comment: @DanRust: Sorry what do you mean by "$\pi_0$ is in one to one correspondence with the path components of $X$" ?Also in the same way one can also study the maps from $S^n$ into $X$ instead of $S^0$ or $S^1$ ?

Comment: $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ is defined to be the set of homotopy classes of base-point preserving maps $(\{0,1\},0) \to (X,x_0)$. This is a set and has a cardinality. It is easy to see that $|\pi_0(X,x_0)| = |P(X)|$ where $P(X)$ is the set of path components of $X$. And yes, if you replace $S^0$ and $S^1$ with $S^n$, then one has the so called 'homotopy groups' - an important family of invariants that generalise the fundamental group.

Comment: @DanRust: Do you have any reference like notes/books in mind regarding this ?

Comment: Any text which discusses an introduction to homotopy groups will include these facts. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology is always a good reference I find.

Comment: @DanRust  Thank you,i will have a look at that book.

Comment: In fact the groups $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ are usually distinct for all spaces with more than one point, although the groups at distinct $x_0,x_1$ will be isomorphic if the points lie in the same path component. If the group is abelian, then  that isomorphism is independent of the choice of path from $x_0$ to $x_1$,  It is important in mathematics to realise when this kind of distinction is important. A space is not the same as a space with one base point, or as a space with two base points.

Comment: One more thing that you might want to note that if $X$ is a path connected space and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian, then we have the same fundamental group for all choices of basepoints. In particular, change of basepoint acts by conjugation on the fundamental group.